# Is it possible to delete iframe after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I currently use an iframe in an AJAX upload form, my question is once the file has uploaded to the iframe it appends the data to a div, so would i be safe to say i can remove the iframe once the load has completed?

my js is

```
$("#formsubmit").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');

            $("body").append(iframe);

            var form = $('#theuploadform');
            form.attr("action", "uploader.php");
            form.attr("method", "post");
            form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
            form.attr("target", "postiframe");
            form.attr("file", $('#userfile').val());
            form.submit();

            $("#postiframe").load(function () {
                iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                $("#textarea").html(iframeContents);
                $("#postiframe").remove(); // i thought this would do it but it doesn't
            });

            return false;

        });
```

Also even though i have event.preventDefault(); if i remove the return false at the bottom it still submits the form (refreshes to new page).

my html is:

```
<div id="uploadform">
<form id="theuploadform" action="">
<input id="userfile" name="userfile" size="50" type="file" />
<input id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</div>      
<div id="textarea"></div>
```

So to summarize my questions:

1. Is it possible to delete the iframe after an upload once it has copied to the "textarea"
2. if so the $("#postiframe").remove doesn't work
3. does anyone know why when i remove return false, it reloads the page instead of using the event.preventDefault(); at the beginning

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you try `$(document).find('#postiframe').remove();`?

Comment: thank you that did remove the iframe, however is there a way of removing all of it's child elements aswell?

Comment: it should do! "Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it" [.remove() docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), you sure the other elements are being appended inside?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry wasn't looking propperly. it has removed them but that doesn't seem to have helped on the issue i hoped it would solve. But thank you you answer this question perfectly

Comment: No problem! Still feels like I've only half answered your question! :D, updated my answer @LiamSorsby

Comment: don't worry was perfect for what i wanted to do! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<iframe>` is being appended to the window document through JavaScript after page load, use:

```
$(document).find('#postiframe').remove();
```

That'll transverse through the DOM and find your newly appointed `<iframe>`, and then remove it dynamically from the DOM as hoped.

Try `<input type="button" />` to treat the form instead of `<input type="submit" />`, if you still want to handle the `<input type="submit" />` form submission still, try:

```
$('#theuploadform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

function instead, that'll allow jQuery to prevent the default behaviour of the entire form and all it's child elements.